# Overriding inline CSS using jQuery applies for a while is then gone afterwards. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the inline CSS style of top which is by default provided by jQuery using jQuery CSS() class. But it applies for a while and then it is again switched to old inline CSS top style.

Why is this happening?

see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fari1991/Qn8KR/).

this is what I have done:

```
<script>
`$(".popbutton").on('click',function(e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20, //Get X coodrinates
    mousey = e.screenY + 20; //Get Y coordinates
    var e = jQuery(this);
    this.timer=setTimeout(function () {
        e.popover("show");     
    },600);
    var menu = $(".popbutton").next(),
    menuWidth = menu.width(), //Find width of tooltip
    menuHeight = menu.height(), //Find height of tooltip
    menuVisY = $(window).height() - mousey, //Distance of element from the bottom of viewport
    heightY=$(this)[0].scrollHeight-(1.2*menuHeight);
    $(menu).css('top','100px');
    });
});`

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of this code:

```
this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
        e.popover("show");
    }, 600);
```

When you click the button, the position is calculated correctly but e.popover('show') again changes the position after a delay of 600ms.

Comment: No problem. Mark this as answer if it answers your question